# box-shadow with scrollbar in textarea is flaky.. :(

Tags: css

Look at the edges. I been trying to fix this for two days now, throw at it everything everywhere. The problem is when the scrollbar appears this happens. Note it's the same when scrollbar is unstyled. What do you think?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Styled component code:

```
padding: 6px;
resize: none;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: inherit;
background-color: #e4e4e4;
color: black;
outline: none;
border: none;
&:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2d8cff;
    background-color: ${Colors.primary};
}
& {
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 16px;
        cursor: initial;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: transparent;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #c1c1c1;
        border: solid 4px transparent;
        cursor: initial;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #7d7d7d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this using box-sizing: border-box and using border instead of boxshadow. In border then has to be specified in not focus state too, to the same color as background.